# Parse query finds two objects when there is only one

Tags: ios, objective-c, parse-platform

I have the following code to find the objects in a custom class. For some reason it is finding two of the same object (self.addedArray2's count is 2, but on Parse data table online, there is only one). Do you see why it is finding the same object twice?

```
self.array2 = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    self.addedArray2 = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    PFQuery *query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"Friends"];
    [query whereKey:@"user" containsString:[[PFUser currentUser] objectForKey:@"username"]];
    [query findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *objects, NSError *error) {
        for (Friends *currentFriend in objects) {
            self.relation = currentFriend.friendsRelation;
            self.addedRelation = currentFriend.addedRelation;
            self.query = [_relation query];

            [[_relation query] findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *objects, NSError *error) {
                [self.array2 addObjectsFromArray:objects];

                [[_addedRelation query] findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *objects, NSError *error) {
                    [self.addedArray2 addObjectsFromArray:objects];

                    [self.segmentControl setTitle:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Friends (%lu)", (unsigned long)[self.array2 count]] forSegmentAtIndex:0];
                    [self.segmentControl setTitle:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Added Me (%lu)", (unsigned long)[self.addedArray2 count]] forSegmentAtIndex:1];
                    NSLog(@"Number 1: %@", [self.addedArray2 objectAtIndex:0]);
                    NSLog(@"Number 2: %@", [self.addedArray2 objectAtIndex:1]);

                }];
            }];
        }
    }];
```

It is logging "Number 1" then "Number 1" then "Number 2". It looks like that code is being run twice and adding it again. How do I fix that? With all this nesting, I don't really see what I can do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For your key "user" of the Friends class, if it String that holds the user's username, try replacing:

```
[query whereKey:@"user" containsString:[[PFUser currentUser] objectForKey:@"username"]];
```

with this and let me know if that changes anything:

```
[query whereKey:@"user" equalTo:[[PFUser currentUser] objectForKey:@"username"]];
```

If it is a pointer to a user object, however, then you will want your query to resemble something along these lines:

```
[query whereKey:@"user" equalTo:[User currentUser]];
```

If either of my assumptions are wrong, let me know because I do not know the structure of your classes, but I will try and figure it out.

Comment: The custom class has a key "user" which is just a string. Making a query where it's equal to the currentUser wouldn't work.

Comment: The first one worked actually (didn't see that at first). Thanks